# determine final destination/url returned by a asp(?) by script

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net

So, I'm sure this will get down voted and I'll be banned from the site because I'm a total newb that asks elementary questions/wrong questions/vague questions that irritate the community. But...I'm not sure where else to turn, this seems to be one of the best communities.

I use a live chat service. And they have this cut/paste bit of markup that you drop into your page and it'll display a jpeg indicating whether or not the chat service is open.

```
https://rci.ehosts.net/netagent/client/invites/chatimage.aspx?style=style0&amp;questid=44D115D4-5242-476F-AE56-6AEECE8E9343&amp;portid=28586436-7974-4E4B-BBDE-73E63BC3EAED&amp;imagelanguage=en-us&amp;customopenimage=https%3A//rci.ehosts.net/netagent/custfiles/en_chat_open.gif&amp;customcloseimage=https%3A//rci.ehosts.net/netagent/custfiles/en_chat_closed.gif
```

If you drop that into a browser, it doesn't seem like anything happens. But if you set that as the src attribute of a image tag in a html page, it displays the appropriate image (chat online/chat unavailable).

My question is...can I determine the outcome of that script without dropping it into the page? Via either javascript or php? What'd like to do is make a script of my own that will determine which image is returned and do things other than just displaying the chat online/chat unavailable images.

Thanks!

EDIT: oh, the above url will redirect to the correct image if you change all the & to just &

Comment: whats the specific livechat service? They probably have some kind of api

Comment: It's called Moxie. We asked about an API. Initially, the sales guy said they'd look into pricing. Then later they told us they're not making their API publicly available but we're free to develop/engineer around anything that their service is doing on our site.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following the redirect to see which image it takes me to. It was the only way I could think of. Ended up basically copying example #2, except that I returned the headers location, from the following link:

[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)